# How to translate Promise.try in coffeeScript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, promise, bluebird

Hello I am looking for a code in coffe script which generates this code in javascript

```
Promise = require('bluebird');

 myfunction = function(body) {
  return Promise.try(function() {
    return console.log('OK');
  });
};
```

I have tried something like:

```
   Promise      = require 'bluebird'

   myfunction: (body) ->
    return Promise.try ->
      return console.log('OK')
```

But the result is something like:

```
Promise["try"](function() {});
```

Any idea?? Thanks in advance

Comment: With `=` instead of `:`, it [worksforme](http://coffeescript.org/#try:%20%20%20Promise%20%20%20%20%20%20%3D%20require%20'bluebird'%0A%0A%20%20%20myfunction%20%3D%20(body)%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20return%20Promise.try%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20console.log('OK'))? Not sure why the `console.log` would be dropped.

Comment: Btw, you should be using `myfunction = Promise.method (body) -> console.log('OK')`

Answer (score 3):

I would guess that something is off with the indentation in your file, as the above is correct except:

1. You don't need `return`, as the last statement in a function / block is automatically returned.
2. You should still use `=` for variable assignment, as opposed to `:` which is used for assigning properties when defining an object. It's the same in Coffeescript as in Javascript.

This code:

```
Promise = require 'bluebird'

myfunction = (body) ->
  Promise.try ->
    console.log 'OK'
```

Compiles just fine into:

```
var Promise, myfunction;

Promise = require('bluebird');

myfunction = function(body) {
  return Promise["try"](function() {
    return console.log('OK');
  });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Regarding `Promise.try ->` transpiling into `Promise["try"](function …)` this is due to `try` being a [reserved keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords) in JS.

Comment: This was necessary only till ES3, though, it's just Coffeescript being quite conservative here. One might also use `Promise.attempt` as an alias.

Comment: Then, is there any possibility to generate a Promise.try??

Comment: @GutiMac It does not matter, they are completely equivalent.

Comment: @gutimac it doesn't matter, why do you need Promise.try exactly?

Comment: It is because I have to generate a code exactly equals to a JS code. But in this case if it is impossible I can use attempt. Thanks!